# css: positioning switch and button

Tags: html, css, angularjs-ng-repeat

in the column I have created (col-lg-4) I have a switch and a button. as I am new in CSS, I wanted to know what attributes gives position to them, in the picture I want switch and button have at least 5px distance and button goes to middle vertically. any margin (left, right, top bottom) and align that I change no difference happens.

```
.btn.btn-success{
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2em auto;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 162, 63, 1);
  top: auto;
}
input[type="checkbox"] {
  position: absolute;
  margin-left: 2em auto;
  top: auto;
  opacity: 0;
}
```

[image]

Comment: At least for the checkbox, there is a container or a pseudo element (:before or :after) with a custom interface. The checkbox itself is invisible (opacity: 0). You may try to change the styles of that container. please consider to write up a minimal example/fiddle. The styles you provide are not enough.

Comment: what about the button , if the checkbox (that has switch style) has fix position there, how should I change button position ?

Comment: As far as I can _guess_ the checkbox (switch) has a margin or padding or rests in a container element with a padding. The button has no such padding/margin. You can see the orange border around the elements that is indicating that situation. You may have to change the style properties of the `.btn` class instead of the special class `.btn.btn-success`. As I said: there is more code/example needed.